# Error installing OS updates -- "Too few items to process"

Tags: updates, apt

I was downloading OS updates as per usual while working, and when I finished working I realized the installation had gotten stuck. I was trying to install another package and wanted to use `apt`, which meant access to `dpkg`. After frustrating myself trying to cancel the update and try again, I tried `dpkg --configure -a`, to no avail. Finally, I ran `killall dpkg` against better judgment. I was able to restart dpkg and install my package, but now when I go to install OS updates again I'm confronted with the following message:
[image: There Was An Error Installing Operating System Updates]

Am I safe to move on and expect the next updates to arrive normally? If not, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Yes i have the same problem too.I update via terminal but the problem still insists.

Comment: How do you update via terminal?

Comment: Yes, sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade.And then this window.From what i understand few repositories are obsoleted.Do i have to remove them manually?   https://imgur.com/a/yXpOi

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt autoremove`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so, I believe that is just the way that EOS says you are up to date.   When that happened to me I was able to update without a problem later on.

Thanks.

PS, I am not an authority in EOS I am speaking from experience.

Comment: Ok, thanks! If nobody has more information in the next little while, I'll accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Sadly I've had problems with my wireless.  So the App store is does not work when a different wifi is working in the background which is what I use.  So, sometime I have to update manually on a terminal. Why don't you do a "sudo apt update" to see if it works?  maybe?  :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was relationed to the ppa repositories, it can be another thing for you, but you can check if your case is a ppa problem by going to the console and typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

[image]

you can check for any errors shown. If something is not right, try to temporarily remove the respective ppa list file on folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it was java ppa.
I unselected java ppa via synaptic and reload the update and it was fine.